# Magento 2 invalid form key. please refresh the page issue

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, magento2.3.5-p1

I am facing an "invalid form key. please refresh the page" when customer login and click on any add to cart button. the website on domain name and tried a lot of options like change max_input_vars values remove cookies etc. but issue not resolved. I am using a custom theme for the website.
On mobile sometimes adding product to cart showing "your session has been expired".

Answer (score 0):

Check **core_config_data** table in DB and make sure that **web/cookie/cookie_domain** is set up corretly.

If the domain of your store is domain.com then the value of web/cookie/cookie_domain should be the same.

Comment: It have the same values